# Announcement Bar as header SquareSpace

Tags: header, code-injection, squarespace

I want to use Square space's announcement bar as the header for my site. I have seen others doing this and using the div "sqs-announcement-bar" but have not been able to use code injection to make it work. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is not done via code injection. Under the Marketing menu > Engagement > Announcement bar is where you will find the option to activate this feature. No code is needed. This can be modified with CSS.

[image: Squaresspace]